# Create Iceberg tables on S3 and Hive on-prem

Tags: amazon-s3, hive

I have installed Hive Metastore on my K8S cluster. I configured it's hive-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3.endpoint</name>
        <value> ip:port </value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3.path.style.access</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
   <property>
      <name>fs.s3.access.key</name>
      <value> {accessKey} </value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>fs.s3.secret.key</name>
      <value> {secret} </value>
   </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId</name>
        <value> {accessKey} </value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
        <value> {secret} </value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3.connection.ssl.enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3.path.style.access</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
```

I am using S3 on-prem. And when trying to create a table via Trino like this:

```
create table if not exists lakehouse.test_schema.test_table(
col1 varchar
) with (
 location = 's3://hivetest/test_table)
```

I am getting the following error:

> Got exception: java.net.UnknownHostException
> hivetest.s3.amazonaws.com: Name or service not known

The metadata files(.avro and .json) files of Iceberg are created on the S3 location. But for some reason, Hive can not create the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `hadoop-aws-2.7.4.jar` which does not support `fs.s3.path.style.access`

the hadoop-aws.jar supports `fs.s3.path.style.access` from version 2.8.0.

Upgrading my hive metastore to a newer version that includes `hadoop.version >= 2.8.0`

This can be found there: https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/pom.xml

search for `hadoop.version` in different version releases